# Error when form is open on multiple computers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code in Excel that works great when the form is used by one person at a time. As soon as this form is open on multiple machines on the network, it gives an error msg.

The Error Msg reads:
Run-time error '1004':
Document not saved. The document may be open, or an error may have encountered when saving.

When clicking on Debug, it highlights the following line:
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat 0, FileName

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim d As Date
    Dim m As String
    Dim dy As String
    Dim yr As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim a1 As String
    Dim b1 As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dr As String

    dr = "G:\Operations\Expedite Requests"

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
myarr = Array("Date", "Customer", "PO#", "Workorder#", "Part Number", "Requested Due Date", _
            "Original Promise Date", "Special Note(s)", "Material Substitutions", "Requested By")
j = 0
With ws
    A5 = .Range("A5").Value
    A9 = .Range("A9").Value
    For i = 3 To 21 Step 2
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
            msg = msg & myarr(j) & vbLf
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Next
    If msg <> vbNullString Then
        If MsgBox("Form is not complete. Do you want to continue?" & vbLf & _
            "(Please Type N/A If The Information is not Avalaible)" & vbLf & "Following information is missing:" & vbLf & msg, vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then
                Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End With

Set ws = Sheets("Expedite Form")
d = Date
m = Month(d)
dy = Day(d)
yr = Year(d)

FileName = dr & "\" & yr & "-" & m & "-" & dy & " " & A5 & A9
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat 0, FileName
With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim strBody As String
    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A21")
        strBody = strBody & cell.Value & vbNewLine
    Next
    .To = "TEST1@TEST1.com"
    .CC = "TEST2@TEST2.com;
    .BCC = "TEST3@TEST3.com"
    .Subject = "Expedite Request"
    .Body = strBody
    .attachments.Add dr & "\" & yr & "-" & m & "-" & dy & " " & A5 & A9 & ".pdf"
    .Send  'use .Display to display email; use .send to send email
    MsgBox ("Email Sent To Operations Team")


End With

Call resetForm

End Sub

Sub resetForm()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").Value = ""
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").Value = ""
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A9").Value = ""
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A11").Value = ""
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A13").Value = ""
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A15").Value = ""
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A17").Value = ""
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A19").Value = ""
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A21").Value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Are `A5` and `A9` variables declared anywhere? Looks like this might result in multiple people trying to save the file under the same file name. Also consider working off a local copy of the file.. or is it opened "as read-only" by everyone? Can the exported file not be local?

Comment: This spreadsheet lives on a network drive and I have created it for people to use when they need a make a request. Once the form is filled out, they hit a button and it sends an email with the filled out form to the needed personnel. It also saves the form on the network drive with date, work order, and customer name.

Comment: Yeah, saw that too late - edited comment accordingly. Still, they're not declared. `Option Explicit` should be specified, and all variables should be declared.

Comment: I have added "Option Explicit" at the top and "myarr" is not defined. What should it be defined as?

Comment: Could be `Dim myarr As Variant`. Note that `Option Explicit` prevents a lot of facepalm-worthy bugs caused by... typos. You can make the VBE enforce it consistently, by ticking the "require variable declaration" checkbox in Tools/Options.

Comment: Now "j" is not defined where j = 0. I am not good at defining everything that's why I avoid it. I usually don't know what it needs to be defined as.
Is there a way to see all non-defined variables all at once?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189482/discussion-between-death-magnetic-and-mathieu-guindon).

Comment: You dont necessarily need to define a variable as Long or String etc etc.  You can just use `Dim J` and Excel will default the variable to variant I believe.

Comment: @ZackE true - except a `Variant` can hold literally anything, and can and will change subtype if it's assigned a value of another type; this has caused bugs before. The language has a type system, might as well use it. You don't see anyone advocating to declare everything as `dynamic` in C#.

Comment: @ZackE also, Excel has absolutely nothing to do with this, the language is VBA, the *host* is Excel, and the only thing that does is it makes the Excel type library (aka *object model*) referenced and locked (can't be removed or reprioritized) in the VBA project.